# Qual a diferença entre SET e SETX?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd, variáveis-de-ambiente

Para fixar uma nova variável de ambiente no Windows verifiquei que há os comandos **SET** e **SETX**.

Qual é a diferença exata dos dois comandos?

Comment: Tem um exemplo [aqui](http://batcheero.blogspot.com.br/2008/02/set-and-setx.html) também!

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [`SET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Atribui os valores imediatamente na sessão de *shell* que você está trabalhando agora. Morre quando ele for finalizado. Ele está embutido no próprio *shell*, ele é apenas um comando reconhecível pelo `cmd`.

## [`SETX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Atribui os valores para todas as novas sessões de *shells* criadas e não perde mais até ser alterado por outro `SETX`. As sessões que já estão rodando não são afetadas. Ele é um executável utilitário a parte, portanto só funciona se ele estiver acessível. Com `-m` pode ser aplicado para todos os usuários. É a única forma de modificar as variáveis de ambiente programaticamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Rapido demais :)

Comment: Então posso setar o JAVA_HOME global com SETX ao invés de ir na janela de variáveis de ambiente?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart exatamente.

Comment: Sensacional. Sugiro mencionar algo em relação a isso na tua resposta. Que é um set "global". Outra coisa, é para todos usuários ou somente o atual? Pode complementar também!

Comment: @MurilloGoulart todos precisa usar `-m`.

Answer (score 7):

#### `Set`

Modifica as variáveis de ambiente do *shell* (janela) que está em execução. O novo valor fica disponível imediatamente, porém ele é temporário. A modificação não vai afetar o resto do sistema operacional.

#### `Setx`

Modifica as variáveis de ambiente permanentemente. Isto afeta todos os *shells* que serão abertos no futuro e não é válido para os que estão em execução no momento. Será necessário fechar e abri-lo novamente para que as mudanças estejam disponíveis.